# What is the befault behaviour for Tensorflow.js fitDataset() if no validation dataset is specified?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow.js

How does Tensorflow **compute the fitting loss** and **what does it compute it against** if no `validationData` is specified? It is an **optional parameter** and fitting runs even if you don't specify it, which is what I'm doing in my code right now. How is it different from specifying an explicit validation dataset?

```
    model.fitDataset(dataset, {
        epochs: 30,
        validationData: validationDataset, // <--- What is the behaviour if this optional parameter is not set?
    });
```

I didn't find any info in the documentation on it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The model fits on the training set. No validation set is needed. If you have a validation set than at the end of an epoch the validation images are fed into the trained model and a prediction is made. The prediction is than compared to the true value of the image file to determine the validation accuracy.

Comment: is there kind of a rule of thumb when specifying a validation set is preferred over comparing to the training set?